# Links in bootstrap nav appearing below menu items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used Bootstrap's nav classes for navigation menus on several projects, but never run into this before and after poking the code for this all day, I just can't seem to figure out what's causing the links in the menu items to appear below the actual menu item.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>   
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>

<style>
    .topbar {
        background-color: #572700;
        width: 100%;
        /* display: block; */
        height: 45px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    .brownbar-text-header {
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 18px; 
        display: table-cell;
        height: 45px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }


    header div  .container-fluid  {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
    }

    .brownbar-text-header a {
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .brownbar-text-header a:hover {
        transition: color 0.1s ease 0s;
        transition-property: color;
        transition-duration: 0.1s;
        transition-timing-function: ease;
        transition-delay: 0s;
        color: #3a9b81;
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
</style>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="row topbar">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topbar-nav" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topbar-nav">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav brownbar-text-header">
                        <li>
                        Welcome User <a href="/auth/logout">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>&nbsp; Some Text Goes Here <a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li>&nbsp; Some Text Goes Here <a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li>&nbsp; Some Text Goes Here <a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li>&nbsp; Some Text Goes Here <a href="#">Link</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text inside your list tags is wrapping.  Just put the whole thing inside a span, like so:

```
<li><span>Some Text Goes Here <a href="#">Link</a></span></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correct I think I found a solution :)

Your li's are wrong

```
<li>&nbsp; Some Text Goes Here <a href="#">Link</a></li>
```

You need to do it like this:

```
<li><a href="#">Some Text Goes Here</a></li>
```

Here is your [jsfiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/sr51w6s2/1/)

Also if this is intended, the reason why your 'Link' goes below your navbar is that you put a fixed height on your .topbar class of 45px, you could remove the height as in my jsfiddle, and it will go as far as there is content for it to show :)

Hope I could help you out

// Marc Hjorth

Comment: But I don't necessarily want all of the text to be inside of the href link. The height property of the topbar class was contributing to the problem, but did not resolve the links issue. @rby 's answer actually solved the problem by using a <span>. Thanks for looking though.